# Or correct way to speed up spring response?

Tags: java, spring

I have spring on back-end. My controller:

```
    private boolean time2Update = true;
    private Algo14web al;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/lab/getAlgo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Algo14web  getPicksByLeague(@RequestBody String[] request) {

        if(this.time2Update){
            Algo1DAO ad = new Algo1DAO();

            // Long task
            al = new Algo14web(ad.getAlgo(Integer.parseInt(request[0])), "under", Double.parseDouble(request[1]));
            this.time2Update = false;
        }


        return al;   
    }
```

If I correct understand `al` object is stored in RAM.

My question or correct way to store objects like on top to speed up controller response?  (Or it is good idea keep al on ram or better every time to initialize new one?)

example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lab/getAlgo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Algo14web  getPicksByLeague(@RequestBody String[] request) {     
        Algo1DAO ad = new Algo1DAO();

        // Long task
        Algo14web al = new Algo14web(ad.getAlgo(Integer.parseInt(request[0])), "under", Double.parseDouble(request[1]));

        return al;   
}
```

Comment: Ok, all java objects will be on RAM (unless to serialize them to a file or something but then they would not be alive)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by - *My question or correct way to store objects like on top to speed up controller response?*?

Comment: Or it is good idea keep `al` on ram or better every time to initialize new one?

Comment: Every live java object will be on RAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object allocation in Java is extremely cheap, you are not saving anything by reusing the "reference slot".

In fact, (in general) you are more likely to cause yourself problems because by reusing it, for a start you make the controller no longer thread-safe (ignoring the time2Update field which already breaks this) and you would need to configure Spring to give you a new controller instance for every request and ensure nobody comes along later and changes that configuration causing hard-to-debug problems.

By re-allocating the object every time you also help the JVM do correct escape analysis (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis) allowing it to optimise and tune the code better.

In short, do not worry about these kinds of micro-optimisations.  Write the code stating exactly what you want it to do, let the JVM figure the rest out.  **Only if** you have performance issues do you then get out a profiler and start tweaking to this sort of level based on proven numbers.